unresolved import `try_runtime_cli` and cannot find function `memory_teardown`
I am working on upgrading a runtime that is dependent on substrate-release branch v0.9.25. I was trying to integrate try-runtime. Since this is a pretty old substrate-release I was referring to the docs here (prior to their migration). Whenever i run cargo check -p edgeware-cli --features try-runtime I get a whole bunch of error as follows as shown here. This is the commit i am running cargo check on. If i do not include this specific change/commit everything at the least compiles. I am having difficulty trying to understand what's causing these errors. Some of the notable errors are:
error[E0432]: unresolved import `try_runtime_cli`
  --> node/cli/src/cli.rs:24:5
   |
24 | use try_runtime_cli::TryRuntimeCmd;
   |     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ use of undeclared crate or module `try_runtime_cli`

error[E0433]: failed to resolve: use of undeclared crate or module `try_runtime_cli`
   --> node/cli/src/cli.rs:151:13
    |
151 |     TryRuntime(try_runtime_cli::TryRuntimeCmd),
    |                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ use of undeclared crate or module `try_runtime_cli`

and
  error[E0425]: cannot find function `memory_teardown` in module `sandbox`
    --> /home/raj/.cargo/git/checkouts/substrate-7e08433d4c370a21/3348e14/primitives/sandbox/src/host_executor.rs:58:12
     |
  58 |         sandbox::memory_teardown(self.memory_idx);
     |                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ not found in `sandbox`

  error[E0425]: cannot find function `memory_new` in module `sandbox`
    --> /home/raj/.cargo/git/checkouts/substrate-7e08433d4c370a21/3348e14/primitives/sandbox/src/host_executor.rs:74:18
     |
  74 |         match sandbox::memory_new(initial, maximum) {
     |                        ^^^^^^^^^^ not found in `sandbox`

  error[E0425]: cannot find function `memory_get` in module `sandbox`
    --> /home/raj/.cargo/git/checkouts/substrate-7e08433d4c370a21/3348e14/primitives/sandbox/src/host_executor.rs:82:13
     |
  82 |             sandbox::memory_get(self.handle.memory_idx, offset, buf.as_mut_ptr(), buf.len() as u32);
     |                      ^^^^^^^^^^ not found in `sandbox`


